# How to add crontab in FreeBSD

Tags: cron, freebsd

I am trying to add crontab in FreeBSD but it is not working :

I have used this to add :  `sudo crontab -e -u vaibhav`

```
@daily /home/vaibhav/applications/comparison/scrapy
```

but it not working .Can someone please help me. Is their is any way to check whether crontab is able to run this script. Like `--run-parts` in `Ubuntu`

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific about _what_ goes wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are logged in as `vaibhav`, you don't need to `su` or `sudo` to edit your own crontab. (Note that `sudo` is not part of the freebsd base system. If you want to use it, you should install it from ports.)

Make sure that you  can run `/home/vaibhav/applications/comparison/scrapy` from the command line. I.e. the file should be executable and any interpreter that it needs whould be in the $PATH.

When something goes wrong with a cron command, the owner of the crontab gets a mail. Make sure that your mail is configured correctly.